# Breaking down string and storing it in array

Tags: c, cstring, strtok

I want to break down a sentence and store each string in an array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char* strArray[40];
    char* writablestring= "The C Programming Language";
    char *token = strtok(writablestring, " ");


    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(strArray[i], token);
        printf("[%s]\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps giving me segmentation error and I cannot figure it out. I believe it has something to do when I copy the token to my array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because `writablestring` isn't writable at all. Attempting to write to a string literal is undefined behavior and **`strtok` writes to it** (that's right, `strtok` modifies its argument).

To make it work, try:

```
char writablestring[] = "The C Programming Language";
```

There's also a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Another problem is that you didn't allocate memory for your array of character pointers (so those pointers point to nothing).

```
char* strArray[40]; /* Array of 40 char pointers, pointing to nothing. */
```

Maybe try this ?

```
/* Careful, strdup is nonstandard. */
strArray[i] = strdup(token);

/* Or this. */
strArray[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
strcpy(strArray[i], token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the example in the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/):

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

...where...

> **str** - 
>   C string to truncate. The contents of this string are modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens).
>   Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.
>
> **delimiters** - C string containing the delimiters.
>   These may vary from one call to another.
>
> **Return Value** - 
>   A pointer to the last token found in string.
>   A null pointer is returned if there are no tokens left to retrieve.

You need that first string to me modifiable and you need to allocate memory for the outputs e.g.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    const int numOfStrings = 128;
    char* strArray[numOfStrings];
    char writablestring[]= "The C Programming Language";
    char *token = strtok(writablestring, " ");

    for( int j = 0; j < numOfStrings; j++ )
    {
        strArray[j] = new char[40];
    }

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(strArray[i], token);
        printf("[%s]\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```