# Split a string and store into an array of strings

Tags: c, strtok

as a part of a program aiming to store a dictionary and replace words according to it,i wrote a function which will basically split(using `strtok`) a string to its words(seperated by spaces),and will store each word into an array of strings.
The code is as follows:

```
void StoreArr(char * original,char ** dest)
            {
                int i=0;

                char * token =strtok(original, " ");
                dest[i]=malloc(sizeof(token));
                strcpy(dest[i],token);
                ++i;

                while(token!=NULL)
                {
                        dest[i]=malloc(sizeof(token));
                        strcpy(dest[i],token);
                        printf("%s",token);
                        token =strtok(NULL, " ");
                        ++i;
                }

            }
```

i passed the following variables:

```
         char * File = "";
         File=malloc(Length(Text)*(sizeof(char)));
         char ** Destination[Count(' ',File)];
```

the length of destination is the number of words.
once the program is run,it terminates itself without displaying the text
it is called using `StoreArr(File,Destination);`

edit:

```
int Length(FILE * file)
            {
                 long result;
                    long origPos = ftell(file);//original start position of file
                    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);//move to end of file
                    result = ftell(file);//return value at end
                    fseek(file, origPos, SEEK_SET);//rewind to beginning
                    return result;
            }
            int Count(char a,char * b)
            {
                int i=0;
                int count=0;
                while(b[i]!='\0')
                {
                if(b[i]==a || b[i]=='\n')
                    ++count;
                ++i;
                }
                return count+1;
            }
```

?i get a warning "passing argument 1,2 of 'StoreArr' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"
Thanks in advance.

p.s:[Breaking down string and storing it in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056146/breaking-down-string-and-storing-it-in-array?rq=1)

the code in the last post is the same as mine,yet mine does not work.i suspect those 2 lines form a problem,i do not know why:

```
 dest[i]=malloc(sizeof(token));
                    strcpy(dest[i],token);
```

Comment: Enable more warnings, if you don't already have. Warnings are *very often* signs that you are doing something that you should not be doing.

Comment: Also, please post post a *complete* example, explaining things like what `Length` and `Count` is. Preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And a last thing, it would probably be better to loop while `strtok` doesn't return `NULL`. E.g. `while (token != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: i added the 2 functions,and changed it to the while(even though in this case it does not relate).any other solution for the matter?i get a warning "passing argument 2 of 'StoreArr' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Comment: i get a warning "passing argument 1,2 of 'StoreArr' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, you look like you may have *undefined behavior* in your code.

With the declaration of `Destination` you have an array of pointers to a pointer, and I don't know if that's what you want. You also need to allocate all the pointers.

You also have to be careful as `strtok` modifies the string it tokenizes, so you can't pass a literal or constant string.

---

If it was me, I would do something like this instead:

```
char **Destination = NULL;
StoreArr(Original, &Destination);
```

And have the function like this

```
size_t StoreArr(char *original, char ***destination)
{
    if (original == NULL || destination == NULL)
        return 0;

    size_t size = 0;
    char *token = strtok(original, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        /* (re)allocate array */
        char **temp = realloc(*destination, sizeof(char *) * (size + 1));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            /* Allocation failed, free what we have so far */
            if (*destination != NULL)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                    free((*destination)[i]);
                free(*destination);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        /* Set the destination pointer */
        *destination = temp;

        /* Duplicate the token */
        (*destination)[size++] = strdup(token);

        /* Get next token */
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return size;
}
```

The function now dynamically allocates new entries as needed, and returns the number of entries in the array or `0` on error.

Comment: thank you very much,but i was aiming to solve my current code(As i would like to learn from the mistakes).as for the strtok changing the string - i do not mind,i simply need it to transfer the contents into the array.destination SHOULD be an array of strings(char arrays).cant i avoid allocation?

Comment: @user3005945 You can avoid explicit allocations by having an array of arrays, like `char Destination[X][Y];`, that's the only way.

Comment: okay.in case i do use allocation,how can i change my existing code?should i simply add an allocation for each cell?also,is my Destination considered an array of strings?

Comment: @user3005945 If `dest` already is a properly allocated array of strings, then just use `strdup` to duplicate each string.

Comment: okay.so my question is : how do i create a proper a properly allocated array of strings,and why should i duplicate each?i simply want to move each of the split words from the original string(char *) into each cell in the array.i do know the number of strings i need to store,that is why my destination array is set with a size.again,i appologize for the ignorance,i am a beginner in c and simply wanting to learn it from experiencing.

Comment: i edited my question with an allocation for the array,yet it still does not print anything.any thoughts?

Comment: can anyone possibly help?this is quite urgent.i keep getting  passing argument 2 of 'StoreArr' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] from the calling(StoreArr(File,Destination);)